# Before/After Scenario not working in jbehave serenity BDD

Tags: java, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Before/After Scenario not working in jbehave serenity BDD
serenity.version 1.2.3-rc.5
serenity.jbehave.version 1.21.0

Eg

```
public class UploadDocumentWhatStep {

@BeforeScenario
    public void beforeEachScenario(){
        System.out.println("in before");
    }

@Given("Sample Given")
    public void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("in given");
    }
@When("Sample When")
    public void action() {
        System.out.println("in When");
    }
@Then("Sample Then")
    public void action() {
        System.out.println("in then");
    }

@AfterScenario
    public void afterEachScenario(){
System.out.println("in After");
  }
}
```

When i try to run this code the output is

```
Output:
in given
in When
in Then
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked to me:

The JBehave API seems to have changed, it seems you now need to add the ScenarioType parameter:

```
@BeforeScenario(uponType = ScenarioType.ANY)
public void setTheStage() {
    OnStage.setTheStage(new OnlineCast());
}
```

Source: https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-jbehave/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

JBehave determines Scenario by your .story file.  Chances are you either did not define scenarios in your story file or there is a syntax error and it's being ignored.  post your story file here.